# orbot ошибки при компиляции, почему не находится R.java

Tags: java, android

Скачиваю себе в eclipse orbot отсюда: https://github.com/n8fr8/orbot . Не получается запустить проект, валятся ошибки. Много ошибок "R cannot be resolved to a variable", в папке gen нет файла R.java. Project->clean пробовала, перезапускать eclipse тоже. И еще в свойствах проекта не находятся некоторые библиотеки, может ли это повлиять? Еще мне непонятно почему на гитхабе есть папка external (с теми самыми библиотеками которые не находятся) а у меня в проект эта папка не затянулась при импорте с git. please help!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, скорее всего таки действительно надо подключить неподключённые либы. Коли они git-ом не подхватились - сделайте это вручную

Comment: обнаружила что папка external физически есть в папке с проектом, но eclipse ее не показывает в проекте почемуто. попробовала ее добавить руками properties->java build patch->add external class folder. Она не появилась в проекте и ничего не произошло..

Comment: Попробуйте или копирнуть эти либы в папку libs или добавить их [так](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/44): `Project -> properties -> Java build path -> libraries -> add external jars`

Comment: спасибо, но к сожалению не помогло(